# Imagej filter larger than the default 3x3

Tags: java, imagej

Is there a way using the Imagej api to apply a smooth filter using a larger area than the default 3x3. When you run Imagej and select filters you can specify a size, but I can't find that functionality in the api.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What filter do you want to use? When I look at the *Process > Filters* menu, there are a dozen of different filters...

Comment: I'm looking to use the mean filter, which in the api is called smooth.

Comment: I don't find `smooth` in the [ImageJ1 javadoc](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Command Finder](http://imagej.net/Using_the_Command_Launcher) (*Plugins > Utilities > Find Commands...* or just type [**L**]), you can find that *Process > Filters > Mean...* actually launches this command: `ij.plugin.filter.RankFilters("mean")`

[image: The Command Finder window]

Then just look in the API docs of the [`RankFilters` class](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/index.html?ij/plugin/filter/RankFilters.html), and you will find that you can run the mean filter using

```
rank(ImageProcessor ip, double radius, int filterType)
```

with your desired radius and the filter type `RankFilters.MEAN`.